# Merge images to PDF with xconvert-like options

Tags: pdf, convert, pdftk, mupdf

I'm trying to merge images to PDF. Usually the following website is what I use.

https://www.xconvert.com/merge-image-to-pdf

Given the number of images, I'm thinking of automating the conversion with a script this time. Just wondering whether there is any Linux utility which would provide the same/similar options for conversion.

- Page margins
- Paper size
- Layout
- Image Placement
- Image Alignment
- Image Quality
- Image Transparency

I have tried pdftk and muPDF, although the above options do not really match the ones provided by these utilities. Could anyone help? Thank you

Comment: The utility `convert` from ImageMagick (installed by default on Ubuntu) can combine multiple graphcs in one PDF, while images could all be resized to the same size

Comment: thank you @vanadium, i'll look into it